# Is await just a syntatic sugar for create_task in Python Asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Hi given this example below:

[image]

My question is that if the `await` statement is just a syntactic sugar, for example

```
c = await <coro>()
```

is actually equivalent to

```
_c = asyncio.create_task(<coro>())
c = _c.result
```

under the hood?

Comment: `create_task` schedules something with the event loop to make it eligible to run the next time something is awaited (or completed). `await` runs something immediately. The behavior you are seeing is specifically because you are using a jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 The confusion is caused by the OP running the code under Jupyter which runs the event loop inparallel with the GUI. In that environment typing `task = asyncio.create_task(some_coroutine())`, as soon as the user presses enter, the created task gets picked up by the event loop running the entire time, and immediately executed. That's why `task.result()` in the following line provides a result instead of raising an `InvalidStateError`, as you correctly point out.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 This led the OP to conclude that `await x` is mere syntactic sugar for `_tmp = create_task(x)` immediately followed by `_tmp.result` on the following line. But if they ran their code outside Jupyter, or if they just joined the two commands to a single line (`_tmp = create_task(x); _tmp.result`), it would no longer work.

Comment: @user4815162342 oh wow, I didn't realize it worked that way, removing my comment as it may be misleading. thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I guess my point was that your comment was in fact, correct - just not in the (very specific) context of the Jupyter interactive environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent.

### await

`result = await awaitable_object`

suspends the coroutine until the `awaitable_object` is done, then returns it’s result, or raises an exception, which will be propagated. There are three main types of awaitable objects: **coroutines**, **Tasks**, and **Futures**.
`await` expression are only valid within an `async def` and, simply put, runs a coroutine or task **synchronously**.

### create_task

`asyncio.create_task(coro, *, name=None)`
Wrap the `coro` coroutine into a `Task` and schedule its execution soon. Return the Task object. It does not suspend the execution of the current code and does not return the result of the task. `create_task` can be called both within `async def` coroutines and ordinary `def` functions.

Simply put, `create_task` does not execute the task immediately, does not wait its result, but only schedules its execution in the near future.

`Task.result()`

> Return the result of the Task.
> If the `Task` is done, the result of the wrapped coroutine is returned (or if the coroutine raised an exception, that exception is re-raised.)
> If the `Task`’s result isn’t yet available, this method **raises** a InvalidStateError exception.